# Big quote symbols on the beginning and ending of blockquote with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the following effect:

[image]

I am able to put the first one with content and the symbol **'\201C'**, but the second one **'\201D'** always creates a big space between the last line and the one before.
The font in the image is helvetica, that's why it is a little bit different from the jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ynbsy9Lg/

My html is:

```
<div id="aaa-BoxBioBlogger" class="boxBioBlogger">
   <div class="theQuoteBioBlogger">
        <blockquote class="quoteBioBlogger">
            This is a testing message to show the functionality
        </blockquote>
        <span class="fromquoteBioBlogger">- The Guy -</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css, without any attempt of quotes is:

```
#aaa-BoxBioBlogger{
    width: 325px;
    height: 282px;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/mFYYD8J.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.theQuoteBioBlogger {
    position: relative;
    top: 43%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.fromquoteBioBlogger {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.quoteBioBlogger {
    width: 76%;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: The first one? What do you mean? The first quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the quotes first, and then use `line-height` to shift them down slightly:

```css
blockquote {
border:none;
font-family:  Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
margin-bottom:30px;
quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}

blockquote {
    font-size:21px;
}

blockquote:before { 
    content: open-quote;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height: 110%;
    color:#FFFFFF;
} 
blockquote:after { 
    content: close-quote;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height: 110%;
    color:#FFFFFF;
  
}

#aaa-BoxBioBlogger{
    width: 325px;
    height: 282px;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/mFYYD8J.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.theQuoteBioBlogger {
    position: relative;
    top: 43%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.fromquoteBioBlogger {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.quoteBioBlogger {
    width: 76%;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="aaa-BoxBioBlogger" class="boxBioBlogger">
   <div class="theQuoteBioBlogger">
        <blockquote class="quoteBioBlogger">
            This is a testing message to show the functionality
        </blockquote>
        <span class="fromquoteBioBlogger">- The Guy -</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool AJ, but to stop it from adding the gap you should add `vertical-align: text-top;` to the `blockquote:after` so that the closing quote isn't taking vertical space above the last line.  Also its `line-heignt` should be 100%.